# Get array of strings based on a time interval

Tags: javascript

I have two datetimes, e.g.:

```
"start": "2021-04-10T10:05:00+02:00"
"end": "2021-04-10T11:35:00+02:00"
```

What I would like to get out from this is an array of strings based on the duration between the two dates, in e.g. a quarter interval. So basically the above should result in:

```
var timeArray = ["10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30"]
```

I know I can get the time duration between dates from the `intervalToDuration` function in the `date-fns` package, but I am not sure how to create these timestamps from that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Seems like you want to round down to the nearest (interval), then iterate by (interval) up to the last time rounded down by (interval), and create a formatted time-only string based on each. What specific issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getTimeArray(int, d1, d2){

  let d1_ = new Date(d1);
  let d2_ = new Date(d2);

  let min = d1_.getMinutes();
  let m = (min>=0&&min<=14)?0:(min>14&&min<=29)?15:(min>29&&min<=44)?30:(min>44&&min<=59)?45:0;
  d1_.setMinutes(m);
  let arr = [];

  do {
    let gh = ("0"+d1_.getHours()).slice(-2);
    let gm = ("0"+d1_.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    arr.push(`${gh}:${gm}`);

    d1_.setMinutes(d1_.getMinutes()+int);
    
  } while (d1_ <= d2_);

  return arr;
}

let arr = getTimeArray(15, "2021-04-10T10:05:00+02:00", "2021-04-10T11:35:00+02:00");

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break it down like this, then iterate from start to end time, pushing each quarter hour into the array.

```
var start = "2021-04-10T10:05:00+02:00"
start = start.split("T")[1].split("+")[0]
startHour = start.split(":")[0]
startMin = start.split(":")[1]


var end = "2021-04-10T11:35:00+02:00"
end = end.split("T")[1].split("+")[0]
endHour = end.split(":")[0]
endMin = end.split(":")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across the same case and got the following solution.

Let's play with the time rather than the DateTime.

`timeslot` will be the main function and it takes three arguments `timeInterval`, `startTime` and `endTime`.

```
timeInterval => in minutes
startTime => min 00:00 and max 24:00
endTime => min 00:00 and max 24:00


const timeslots = (timeInterval, startTime, endTime) => {
    // get the total minutes between the start and end times.
    var totalMins = subtractTimes(startTime, endTime);

    // set the initial timeSlots array to just the start time
    var timeSlots = [startTime];

    // get the rest of the time slots.
    return getTimeSlots(timeInterval, totalMins, timeSlots);
}

// Generate an array of timeSlots based on timeInterval and totalMins

const getTimeSlots = (timeInterval, totalMins, timeSlots) => {
    // base case - there are still more minutes
    if (totalMins - timeInterval >= 0) {
        // get the previous time slot to add interval to
        var prevTimeSlot = timeSlots[timeSlots.length - 1];
        // add timeInterval to previousTimeSlot to get nextTimeSlot
        var nextTimeSlot = addMinsToTime(timeInterval, prevTimeSlot);
        timeSlots.push(nextTimeSlot);

        // update totalMins
        totalMins -= timeInterval;

        // get next time slot
        return getTimeSlots(timeInterval, totalMins, timeSlots);
    } else {
        // all done!
        return timeSlots;
    }
}

// Returns the total minutes between 2 time slots

const subtractTimes = (t2, t1) => {
    // get each time's hour and min values
    var [t1Hrs, t1Mins] = getHoursAndMinsFromTime(t1);
    var [t2Hrs, t2Mins] = getHoursAndMinsFromTime(t2);

    // time arithmetic (subtraction)
    if (t1Mins < t2Mins) {
        t1Hrs--;
        t1Mins += 60;
    }
    var mins = t1Mins - t2Mins;
    var hrs = t1Hrs - t2Hrs;

    // this handles scenarios where the startTime > endTime
    if (hrs < 0) {
        hrs += 24;
    }

    return (hrs * 60) + mins;
}

// Gets the hours and minutes as intergers from a time string

const getHoursAndMinsFromTime = (time) => {
    return time.split(':').map(function (str) {
        return parseInt(str);
    });
}

// Adds minutes to a time slot.

const addMinsToTime = (mins, time) => {
    // get the times hour and min value
    var [timeHrs, timeMins] = getHoursAndMinsFromTime(time);

    // time arithmetic (addition)
    if (timeMins + mins >= 60) {
        var addedHrs = parseInt((timeMins + mins) / 60);
        timeMins = (timeMins + mins) % 60
        if (timeHrs + addedHrs > 23) {
            timeHrs = (timeHrs + addedHrs) % 24;
        } else {
            timeHrs += addedHrs;
        }
    } else {
        timeMins += mins;
    }

    // make sure the time slots are padded correctly
    return String("00" + timeHrs).slice(-2) + ":" + String("00" + timeMins).slice(-2);
}
```